# How do I use fmt.Scanf in Go

Tags: parallel-processing, go

I seem to be having a queer problem while getting user input within a for loop in go. 
Here is my [code](http://play.golang.org/p/r2ViReKCrl)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Debug: i : %d ", i)
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &num)
        fmt.Println(num)
    }
}
```

What happens when I run this code is this :

```
Debug: i : 0
Enter next number
1
1
Debug: i : 1
Enter next number
1
Debug: i : 2
Enter next number
2
2
Debug: i : 3
Enter next number
2
Debug: i : 4
Enter next number
3
3
Debug: i : 5
Enter next number
3
Debug: i : 6
Enter next number
4
4
Debug: i : 7
Enter next number
4
Debug: i : 8
Enter next number
5
5
Debug: i : 9
Enter next number
5
```

What I notice is that each iteration of the loop happens twice, Could this be because Go is using parallelism by default and causing both processors to run the code within a for loop?

Comment: As far as I can see, each iteration is done only once, `Debug: i: n` where `n` goes from 0 to 9 suggests exactly that. Or do you mean something else? Here is my session in the terminal: https://gist.github.com/4357860 It works exactly as expected.

Comment: How come your output doesn't match your code?

Comment: @VladimirMatveev If you try to run it on your machine, i think youll see what I mean . Do you see the scanf in the loop? It should read a value from the keyboard 10 times. But for every input I give in, the loop block executes twice. So i increments twice.

Comment: @jdi Im confused about that too

Comment: Print the errors returned from `Scanf` and I suspect all will become clear! If `Scanf` returns an error then num will be unchanged.  I suspect this is something to do with the end of line character on windows being `\r\n`.

Comment: @gprasant, the link I gave holds the copy of terminal session on my computer with your program. It went exactly as your code suggests: print "Debug: i: $n " line -> awaiting number -> I enter the number -> it is printed -> repeat again. However, the output you have given cannot be produced by you program in principle; it can be produced by the program that peterSO has written in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What OS are you using? Windows?

Try this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Debug: i : %d\n", i)
        fmt.Println("Enter next number")
        n, err := fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &num)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(n, err)
        }
        fmt.Println(num)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Debug: i : 0
Enter next number
1
1
Debug: i : 1
Enter next number
2
2
Debug: i : 2
Enter next number
3
3
Debug: i : 3
Enter next number
4
4
Debug: i : 4
Enter next number
5
5
Debug: i : 5
Enter next number
6
6
Debug: i : 6
Enter next number
7
7
Debug: i : 7
Enter next number
8
8
Debug: i : 8
Enter next number
9
9
Debug: i : 9
Enter next number
10
10
```

Comment: Im using windows. I tried your suggestion. Im still having the same problem

Comment: Im sorry, I midded out the '\n' in `fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &num)` . I tried the scanfwith \n and it worked

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is a good suggestion.
the code

```
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
    }
```

will output the reason of this problem.

```
  10 unexpected newline
```

So I change the code to this,  and it works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Debug: i : %d ", i)
        fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &num) // add "\n"
        fmt.Println(num)
    }
}
```

this is because of the different line endings. the windows uses carriage return and line feed(`\r\n`) as a line ending. the Unix uses the line feed(`\n`).

you can use [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) to create a file (a.txt) with `\r` line feed. 
and do this:

```
  go run s.go < input.txt
```

this will work correctly.

Comment: it was a problem with the absense '\n' in the scanf. Is this a windows line ending problem? because I ran the same code above on a friend's mac and it worked perfectly

Comment: this is because of the different line endings. the windows uses carriage return and line feed('\r\n') as a line ending. the Unix uses the line feed('\n').

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out fmt.Scanln(&num) would probably work the same as fmt.Scanf("%d\n",&num), since fmt.Scanln(&num) also check the type of "num".

In other words, if

```
var num float32

fmt.Scanln(&num)
```

you can input floating number from the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i resolved adding "\n" in a scanf format string:
fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &num).