# Inconsistent behavior in Go switch case

Tags: go, switch-statement, case

This is very unusual: given the same input, Go will behave differently at random.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var i string

    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &i)
    fmt.Println(i)

    switch i {
    case "a":
        fmt.Println("good")
    case "b":
        fmt.Println("not good")
    default:
        fmt.Println("bad")
    }
}
```

in Command prompt I run

```
go run test.go
```

then I type

```
"a <enter>"
```

sometimes getting:

```
a
a
good
```

and randomly (about half the time) doing the same thing yields:

```
a
t
bad
```

The installation is go1.3.3.windows-amd64.msi on Windows 7
Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case this is an eol (end of line) issue, try:

```
fmt.Scanf("%s\r\n", &i)
```

This is mentioned in "[How do I use `fmt.Scanf` in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008269/6309)":

> this is because of the different line endings.
>   The windows uses carriage return and line feed('`\r\n`') as a line ending.
>   the Unix uses the line feed('`\n`')

Comment: I rewrote the Scanf as you said, but it does not change the output.  I did however isolate it further:  If I call "go run test.go" and immediately enter the value 'a', before it finishes compiling, it registers as a 't' for some reason.  Odd behavior, likely caused by the compiler/linker and has nothing to do with the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your error.

Don't ignore errors. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i string
    n, err := fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &i)
    if err != nil || n != 1 {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
    switch i {
    case "a":
        fmt.Println("good")
    case "b":
        fmt.Println("not good")
    default:
        fmt.Println("bad")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\>go version
go version go1.3.3 windows/amd64
C:\gopath\src\so>go run test.go
a
a
good
C:\gopath\src\so>go run test.go
b
b
not good
C:\gopath\src\so>go run test.go
t
t
bad
```